# Scaling a web scraping python script via SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh, cluster-computing, scaling

I've recently written a python script that helps in scraping webpages and storing the content in a file called `dump.json`. In my university I'm using around 20 computers (*no root access, only python virtual environment!*) that I have to do this by SSH'ing into each of these machines and running them locally and storing.

For example, I've around 1 Million web pages to scrape for info. The technique I'm employing is to divide this 1 million set into 50,000 web page sets and run each of such sets on my 20 different computers. Something like this:

**./jobs.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh chervil "./scrapper.py 0 && ./scrapper.py 19" &
ssh cherry "./scrapper.py 1 && ./scrapper.py 20" &
ssh betel "./scrapper.py 2 && ./scrapper.py 21" &
ssh arka "./scrapper.py 3 && ./scrapper.py 22" &
ssh classic "./scrapper.py 4 && ./scrapper.py 23" &
ssh fanpalm  "./scrapper.py 5 && ./scrapper.py 24" &
ssh betel "./scrapper.py 6 && ./scrapper.py 25" &
ssh oak "./scrapper.py 7 && ./scrapper.py 26" &
ssh devdar "./scrapper.py 8 && ./scrapper.py 27" &
ssh palm "./scrapper.py 9 && ./scrapper.py 28" &
ssh tulasi "./scrapper.py 10 && ./scrapper.py 29" &
ssh ashoka "./scrapper.py 11 && ./scrapper.py 30" &
ssh willow "./scrapper.py 12 && ./scrapper.py 31" &
ssh sandal "./scrapper.py 13 && ./scrapper.py 32" &
ssh haldi "./scrapper.py 14 && ./scrapper.py 33" &
ssh scicity "./scrapper.py 15 && ./scrapper.py 34" &
ssh bilva "./scrapper.py 16 && ./scrapper.py 35" &
ssh brahmi "./scrapper.py 17 && ./scrapper.py 36" &
ssh orange "./scrapper.py 18 && ./scrapper.py 37"
```

I could write a bash script to make this process more systematic but you get the idea. What I'm doing is basically SSHing into each machine and creating segmented dumps like `dump-1.json`,'`dump-2.json`,.... `dump-37.json` and joining the dumps using `sed *.json > final.json`. As you can see the method that I'm employing looks a bit clumsy.

**Question**

Now, I'm sure there are better solutions out there that will help me achieve this goal of "scaling" or running my script on multiple machines with the option of fine tuning parameters on each system to run . In my case for instance, finally merging my results from different systems (or the same user) more systematically. I've heard of options like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) but I wasn't sure if that is solution best for these needs? What are the best options out there?

My needs being that, only SSH access with no root on my Linux university computers!

I'd like to thrown in a few other options (which i've no clue of) that a few friends of mine suggested. Like [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) which might be a bit too high end for me.

Comment: So you want 20 computers doing the exact same operation? Or you want to fetch partial results from each operation, do some work, then return the final output somewhere? (the later is where Spark is more useful).

Comment: I want 20 computers segmenting the load of my script and returning the output in one file. Spark is a very expensive alternative for me. Is there any university student option?

Comment: Try read about gnu parallel - it knows to scale same script with ssh

Comment: maybe `puppet` it's very simple.
check the video for a short introduction : https://puppet.com/product/how-puppet-works

Comment: The one-step-removed option would be to have one "master" box, that you SSH into, and it does the leg work of splitting the 1M entries into chunks, then **it** SSH's into the other boxes, giving them "instructions".  The other boxes could also copy the list back to the master box (e.g. via `rsync` or `scp`) and the master could perform the joining of the results.  Hosting a database on the master box might also be an option, but I'm not sure how permissive your setup is, it doesn't sound exceptionally so.

Comment: @RobertNavado just had a look at gnu parallel. Doesn't look convincing to me. The commands are just as ugly as i'm doing right now. Having said that, if there is no other option. I would read up more on the documentation if there is no other altenative ::(

Comment: @Loïc puppet it probably an overkill and a pricey option.

Comment: Apache spark is completely free... Where are you seeing that things cost money?

Comment: It might be difficult to setup much of anything useful  without root. Spark needs Java and Scala installed, for example. If just Mapreduce by setting up a Hadoop cluster, that's also requiring root. Building an Apache Mesos cluster - same deal. Basically, how do you even know your algorithm scales at all? What part of the script accepts chunks of data and why can't you start with multi-threading that on a single machine to see how well it does?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep pricey? puppet is free. There is a free open source version.